# CHAVE ESTRANGEIRA MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, chave-estrangeira

Sou iniciante nesse mundo e estou com uma dúvida.

Como faço pra acessar somente uma única linha de uma tabela SQL pelo ID?

Tenho uma tabela "empresa" que possui uma chave estrangeira com o id de outra tabela: tabela "pedidos". Ou seja, no sistema cada empresa tem seus devidos pedidos.

Quando o adm do site acessa sua página, ele tem acesso a essas empresas e os pedidos que foram feitos por elas.

Como faço para que, ao adm entrar no sistema e clicar na página de uma empresa específica os pedidos somente daquela empresa que foi acessada apareçam? Como faço para adicionar/acessar dados somente de uma única linha na tabela MySQL pelo id??

Fico grata!

Comment: Não bastaria fazer `SELECT ... FROM pedidos WHERE id_empresa = 1` (substituindo o 1 pelo id em questão)?

Answer (score 0):

Levando em conta as informações e que é um relacionamento simples, primeiramente você precisaria "juntar" as tabelas "empresa" e "pedidos". Isso é feito por meio do `inner join`, onde você estará referenciando uma tabela à outra por meio de um atributo que elas compartilham entre si (no caso é a chave estrangeira). Se você fizer o join:

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos 
inner join empresa on empresa.idempresa = pedidos.idempresa
```

você poderá retornar todos os dados da tabela pedidos de uma certa empresa, a qual você passaria o id dela na cláusula `WHERE` de sua consulta. De maneira genérica:

```
SELECT * FROM pedidos 
inner join empresa on empresa.idempresa = pedidos.idempresa 
WHERE empresa.idempresa = 1
```

essa consulta exemplo te retorna todos os  pedidos da empresa cujo o id for 1.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, vou tentar aqui!